# Typescript useState React Hook Destructuring Error (Not Returning Array?)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, use-state

I'm futzing about with a simple React app for the first time, and looking to set up a simple MVC to connect with an ASP.NET backend, all being done in Visual Studio 2019 (which has caused some headaches with React). However, now that I'm trying to implement models, I'm finding that all of the suggestions for strongly typing the useState hook aren't working for me.

According to a few tutorials like [this one](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/type-safe-state-modeling-with-typescript-and-react-hooks) or [this one](https://www.carlrippon.com/typed-usestate-with-typescript/), it should be as simple as adding a type in brackets, like `const [state, setState] = useState<Type>({})`, since it has a generic implementation. Unfortunately, for me, this throws the error "**Uncaught TypeError: Invalid attempt to destructure non-iterable instance.**"

This thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42141393/react-js-error-invalid-attempt-to-destructure-non-iterable-instance) suggested that switching from an array to an object by changing the [] to {}, however that simply made the two parameters I passed be undefined, so I had no state or way to update said state.

I went down the path of reading until I had a brief understanding of array destructuring, so I understand that the idea is to pass an array with two constants that will be assigned in-order the elements of the array returned by the useState hook. So, I tried manually destructuring the array, setting a constant `useState[0]` and `useState[1]` separately. When I tried this for an untyped hook, it worked as expected. When I tried this for the typed hook, I got some errors about there not being elements, and upon printing out the object, found not an array like the untyped hook, but a boolean. It seems that a typed useState is returning the value "false" instead of an array.

At this point, my best guess is that I have some dependencies that don't implement the typed useState, but I'm really hitting a stone wall on troubleshooting. Anyone have some idea on what I'm doing wrong?

Edit: The testing file I have set-up -

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import { Product } from '../Models/Product';

const Account = () => {
    //Works as-intended
    const test = useState(5);
    //Returns false when logged
    const test2 = useState<Product>({
        "ProductID": "p#corn", "Description": "Delicious corn", "ImageLink": "https://testlink.com", "Name": "Corn", "Price": "2.99", "Category": "Food"
    });
    
    //What should work, to my understanding, however this makes the route crash when it's navigated to because of the "Inavlid attempt to destructure non-iterable instance
    const [test3, setTest] = useState<Product>({});

    function clickHandler() {
        console.log(test)
    }

    function clickHandler2() {
        console.log(test2)
    }

    return (
        <div className='wrapper'>
            <button onClick={clickHandler}>Test</button>
            <button onClick={clickHandler2}>Test2</button>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Account;
```

The Product model -

```
 export interface Product {
    ProductID: string;
    Description: string;
    ImageLink: string;
    Name: string;
    Price: string;
    Category: string;
    }
```

Comment: Can you share your code. It's really hard to imagine what other code might have done to contribute to this error without being able to investigate e.g. where does your useState import come from, where is it being called. Adding types should never actually change the javascript code which typescript transpiles, it just changes whether the compiler will allow it without errors.

Comment: @cefn While I've been a long-time lurker, this is the first time actually posting, so I'm not totally sure of the proper way to do things. I added it as a code snippet, but I can do screenshots if that works better.
I also didn't include any of my config files, but I've got React 17.0.2 in package.json, so I'm guessing that's what the import is grabbing from.
Thank you for taking a look!

Comment: It's even weirder that as you say the first line with useState does what you think is intended, as this should return an array, containing first a value, and second a setter, not a value at all. I'm starting to wonder if your environment is set up with some JSX config which means it's not interpreting the `<Product>` as a typescript Generic at all, but something else, like a HTML element or something. It certainly seems specific to your environment or config somehow.  I'm going to put together a CodeSandbox which might be a good way for you to work out what's true for the rest of the world.

Comment: What does it print out when you use `console.log(useState<Product>({}))`;

Comment: @cefn It's not just with the `<Product>`, it's also with more generic types like `<Number>` and `<Boolean>`, but JSX config does seem a likely culprit, since I've been having to cobble it together from several different tutorials.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli It just prints out **false**. No object or array is returned. However, `console.log(useState(5))` returns an array containing a state variable of 5 and a function for setting that state.

Answer (score 1):

Here's [a CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-sunset-1qx7z?file=/src/App.tsx) with an example somewhat related to your case, which demonstrates how useState is meant to work on everyone else's machine.

As you will see from testing it and messing with the example I shared, useState with a generic type specified should be fine and dandy and behave just as you expect.

That underlines that there's something about your local machine or project environment which is special to you.

```
import React, { useCallback, useState } from "react";

import "./styles.css";

interface Product {
  Name: string;
  Price: number;
}

const productA = {
  Name: "Corn",
  Price: 2.99
};

const productB = {
  Name: "Frozen Orange Juice",
  Price: 10_000
};

export default function Show() {
  const [product, setProduct] = useState<Product>(productA);

  const toggleProduct = () =>
    setProduct(product === productA ? productB : productA);

  return (
    <div className="App" onClick={toggleProduct}>
      <h1>{product.Name}</h1>
      <h2>{product.Price}</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Since you asked about how to get the best responses...

Ideally when posting try to create a problem case which other people can see failing. If you attempt to do this (e.g. using a CodeSandbox) but it works fine there, then it's a matter of working on cleaning up your own local environment until you figure out what is unique about your setup which makes code break for you but no-one else.

Ideally if you can't create it within a single page repro (sandbox), because it's something to do with your project structure, create a runnable reproduction by sharing the actual project structure and its code and configuration publically on github so people can recreate your problem by checking it out and building/running it. That way they will soon be able to track down what's distinctive about your project.

Often this process of creating a repro will help you figure out the problem anyway - e.g. you start with a vanilla create-react-app typescript skeleton from https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-typescript/ to populate a blank github repo and your problem case suddenly starts working there - now you have a basis for bisecting your problem by adding your project's special features to the simple repro until it breaks.

Comment: Ah! Thank you for both the example and the info about making good posts. I'm still unaware of a lot of the tools for good code sharing, so I'll try to learn more about CodeSandbox and take a look at creating a public github repo so I can do the slow recreation of my project until that functionality breaks, and then share it if I can't figure out where I went wrong in the config.